# NGNX, Passenger, Rails "Resource temporarily unavailable while connecting to upstream"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger, linode

Ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0.1
The application has been running fine for over a year, and hasn't been updated in a week.  However, all of a sudden going to the App returns a 503 error.  The database connection is on another Linode - it's running fine, and I can manually connect to the mysql db from the problem server, this is what the nginx access logs say:

```
2012/06/30 03:20:00 [error] 2277#0: *509 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:20:12 [error] 2277#0: *511 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:20:24 [error] 2277#0: *513 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:20:36 [error] 2277#0: *515 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:20:48 [error] 2277#0: *517 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:21:00 [error] 2277#0: *519 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:21:12 [error] 2277#0: *521 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:21:24 [error] 2277#0: *523 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
2012/06/30 03:21:35 [error] 2277#0: *525 connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.12, server: disco, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "*.*.*.*"
```

Linode says everything is running fine on their end - any ideas that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like there was an Amazon outage which took down our redis database:

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/06/30/amazon_cloud_storm_outage/